# Presentando "The Loop": Una base para escuchar

Tags: discusión, artículo

Hoy la compañía ha publicado un [artículo de blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/), el cual está muy, pero muy largo. Por lo pronto comparto una traducción del "TLDR;" (síntesis) incluida al inicio del artículo.

> Síntesis: Vamos a estar compartiendo nuestro proceso de desarrollo contigo, desde ciclos de retroalimentación a líneas de tiempo. Lo haremos a través de una nueva serie The Loop. Puedes darnos tus ideas sobre lo que te gustaría ver que nosotros hagamos respondiendo a esta encuesta: [Through the Loop](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/Z2YDMRD). También nos gustaría lanzar Capacitación para Moderadores y algunos mecanismos de retroalimenación que nos ayuden a formar decisiones según vayamos creciendo.

Texto original

> TLDR; We’re going to be sharing our product development process with you, from feedback loops to timelines. We’ll be doing so through our new series – The Loop. You can give us your thoughts on what you’d like to see us do by filling out this survey: [Through the Loop](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/Z2YDMRD). We’ll also be releasing Moderator Training and some new feedback mechanisms to help us form decisions as we grow.