# Tema de los pronombres y el género en español

Tags: discusión, convenciones-sociales, código-de-conducta

¿No debería stack [afinar un poco este tema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336366/post-for-clarifications-on-the-updated-pronouns-faq) para los que escribimos en castellano? Para nosotros no es solo un tema de "he" o "she".

> «El pleno está integrado por el presidente o presidenta, el vicepresidente o vicepresidenta y los vocales o las vocales.» Ante ese párrafo pueden ocurrir dos cosas. Una es que parezca normal: de pura saturación terminas acostumbrándote a cualquier imbecilidad. La otra es que nos dé la risa floja. Al principio creí que era un texto chungo. Manipulado. Pero nada de eso: BOPV, ley 9/2004 de la Comisión Jurídica. «Se hace saber a los ciudadanos y ciudadanas», etcétera. Todo trufadito de perlas como ésta: «Un secretario o secretaria que se nombra por el presidente o presidenta (...) entre funcionarios y funcionarias». Y más adelante, con repetición exhaustiva de las titulares o los titulares, las vocales o los vocales, los presentes o las presentes, el secretario o la secretaria, el presidente o la presidenta, se detalla que en ausencia «de uno de los vocales o una de las vocales (...) se procederá al nombramiento de un suplente o una suplente (...). El nombramiento y cese del suplente o la suplente se realizará conforme a lo previsto (...). El tiempo que dure la suplencia se imputará al período de mandato de la vocal o el vocal suplido». Imagino que las feministas galopantes estarán goteando agua de limón con el texto, pero creo que aún podríamos afinar un poquito más. Porque observo cierto déficit de concordancia. Puestos o puestas a ello, «la vocal o el vocal suplido» debería haberse escrito «la vocal o el vocal suplido o suplida», o bien «la vocal o el vocal suplidos o suplidas». Y puestos a hilar fino, lo de «el tiempo que dure la suplencia» también era mejorable escribiendo «el tiempo que dure la suplencia o el suplencio». Pero en fin. Cada maestrillo tiene su librillo.

[Arturo Pérez-Reverte. Las miembras y los miembros. *El Semanal*](http://www.perezreverte.com/articulo/patentes-corso/56/las-miembras-y-los-miembros/)

Comment: Por el momento, la discusión sobre los pronombres y los cambios en el CoC no influyen a los sitios de la red cuyo idioma no es el inglés.

Comment: @Pikoh "No influye a No idioma español". La doble negación me enreda las dendritas ¿a qué te refieres?

Comment: más bien será "cuyo idioma no es el inglés"

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster a veces mis dendritas si que se enredan, y las sinapsis se estrangulan. Me refería a sitios de la red cuyo idioma no es el inglés. He editado mi comentario

Comment: Nótese que el usuario también publicó esta pregunta (en inglés) en Meta.SE [How should the new pronoun policy be applied to Spanish language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339133/209901)

Comment: No se hasta que punto está "bien" marcar como aceptada una pregunta en este tipo de situaciones. La comunidad suele ser la que vota y decide cual es la mejor. Aceptándola es como si esa respuesta fuese la correcta, cuando realmente no lo es, es solo con la que mas de acuerdo puedes estar tu personalmente. Lo digo para que el tema quede abierto para mas posibles opiniones puesto que a mi me parece interesante y es un tema que lleva dando vueltas durante una temporada.

Comment: Relacionado con mi comentario: (en ingles, no he encontrado esto en nuestro meta) [Should discussion questions have an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61760/should-discussion-questions-have-an-accepted-answer)

Comment: Ah bueni me dijeron alguna vez que había que marcar las respuestas. Si aparece una respuesta más elaborada creo que puedo cambiarlo y recompensar a la respuesta más elaborada. Animo a participar en el debate aquí o en el post en ingless en meta SE

Comment: @Universal_learner En los metas de los sitios individuales no hay recompensas en términos de puntos de reputación. Mas que por recompensar uno debe pensar en términos de destacar ya que al marcar una respuesta como aceptada, con excepción de las "autorespuestas", la respuesta aceptada se muestra primero.

Comment: @Rubén la he desmarcado y animo otra vez a participar

Comment: Es bueno traer el debate aquí, pues no queda clara cuándo SE va a decidir qué hacer en los casos que plantea el cambio del Código de Conducta. En Spanish.SE debatimos también al respecto en [Should I avoid editing the forms including “@”, “x” and “-e” when/if seen in posts?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3233/1674), pero sin respuesta oficial de la empresa.

Comment: A todo esto, es bueno verte por aquí! Recuerdo leerte hace un tiempo en Meta.SE mencionando unos futuros exámenes para los que querías prepararte sin distracciones SE-ísticas. Espero que hayan ido bien!

Comment: @fedorqui he pasado el primer examen y me van a dar curro aunque no apruebe el segundo examen, pero tengo en diciembre examen de office y mecanografía y voy el 10 para 13 plazas. Nervios...a ver si saco plaza fija.

Answer (score 13):

> Para nosotros no es solo un tema de "he" o "she".

En inglés las profesiones son de género neutro<sup>1</sup> (*the Police*, *the Baker*, *the Doctor*, *the Politician*, *the Soldier*, *the Programmer*) pero los pronombres tienen género (*him*, *her*).

En español las profesiones tienen género<sup>2</sup> (la/el Policía, la/el Panadera/Panadero, la/el Doctora/Doctor, la/el Soldado, la/el Programadora/Programador) pero la mayoría de los pronombres personales no (tu, su).

Al final el "problema" es el mismo pero "en diferente sitio"…

---

Entrecomillé "problema", porque no es un problema: [en internet nadie sabe si eres un perro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_Internet,_nadie_sabe_que_eres_un_perro) y es difícil de asignar género tanto a muchos de los pseudónimos usados como a muchas de las fotografías usadas como imagen de perfil, así que para decidir el género a usar tomamos decisiones sobre la marcha que en algunos casos no se ajustan a la realidad.

Si la persona sobre la que usamos un género asumido se ofende por haber elegido el género incorrecto entonces el "problema" lo tiene dicha persona: antes de ofenderse tiene opciones más adecuadas, menos dañinas y más constructivas, como por ejemplo expresar cuál es su preferencia de género. Sólo pasa a ser un problema si la persona que se "equivocó" prefiere seguir haciendo algo que molesta a la otra persona.

Pero aún en ese caso el problema lo tienen esas dos personas (ofendida y ofendedora) y es algo que deberán resolver entre ellas; para nada deberán involucrar toda la comunidad de SO cuyas preocupaciones deberían ser programar en lugar de mirar la entrepierna (real o imaginaria) de la gente.

Si a esto le añadimos que hay gente deseando ofenderse por una nimiedad como el género en un contexto en el que el género es irrelevante, elevado a la potencia de añadir a la ecuación géneros fantasía que más que género son una característica de personalidad, tenemos la receta ideal para llevar el sitio al desastre.

Si en el código de conducta tenemos un punto que indica "Se amable con las demás personas", dicho punto ya incluye tratar a la gente con respeto y amabilidad ergo, no hay necesidad alguna de hacer puntos especiales para género u otras características arbitrarias susceptibles de ofender a alguien.

---

<sup>1</sup>Salvo en contadas ocasiones como *the policeman* o *the fireman* que son profesiones tradicionalmente masculinas.

<sup>2</sup>A veces en el nombre de la profesión y a veces en ambos a la vez.

Comment: De eso creo que se quejaba Monica. Al principio pensé dramatismo, pero ella dice algo así como que puso su nombre y que era mujer porque stack aconsejaba. Cuando como dices de toda la vida yo diría que es la ventaja del pseudónimo, es anónimo. Una mujer puede preferir que no se sepa que es mujer. Para mí que se están metiendo "en camisas de once baras" con este tema esta gente de California. No pueden decirte desde California cómo debemos escribir en España o Latinoamérica es mi opinión.

Comment: No me parece correcto tu comparación inicial en el que dices que los pronombres en inglés tienen género y en español no, de hecho comparas pronombres en tercera persona en inglés (him, her) con pronombres en primera persona en español(tu, su). Sin embargo, en primera y segunda persona del singular en ninguno de los dos idiomas tienen género (yo tu/ me-I you), mientras que en tercera ambos tienen (el, ella / he she). En cuanto al resto de tu razonamiento estoy bastante de acuerdo

Comment: @Fran ¿Qué puedo decir? Soy programador, no filólogo. Lo que quería remarcar es que en Inglés hay cosas que no tienen género asociado mientras que en Español si… y viceversa. Pero no escogí el mejor ejemplo por desconocimiento :'(

Answer (score -1):

Justo ayer La Compañía publicó un artículo en el que menciona cambios en la forma en la se comunica y recibe retroalimentación con los miembros de la comunidad así como la creación de un consejo de moderadores.

Considerando esto, primero paciencia porque estamos en las últimas semanas del año y algunas cosas no se van a "mover" hasta el próximo, segundo, en lo que respecta al tema de los pronombres y otros, algo que debemos aprender es que es importante considerar a los que por cualquier razón no desean participar públicamente.

Por ejemplo, el tema de identidad en Internet es un tema controversial ya que mientras para unos es irrelevante para otros sí es relevante. Según entiendo, La Compañía esta haciendo esfuerzos por escuchar a todos, tanto a los que publican en Meta como a los que no. Reto de proporciones enormes tal como La Compañía desea que sea su base de usuarios.

Una de las cosas que está por verse es como vamos a "evolucionar" los que participamos en Meta ante los cambios que vienen.

---

En mi respuesta a la pregunta hecha en inglés en Meta.SE mencioné que la "política de pronombres", en breve, es si alguien solicita usar un proponerme para referirse a dicha persona, hay tres opciones

- Usarlo
- Retirarse
- Ignorar la petición y atenerse a ser suspendido y en el caso de los moderadores diamantados podría perder su diamante y los privilegios asociados a este.

---

En lo personal dudo mucho que vaya entrar en vigor la política de pronombres pronto, en particular porque seguramente este será uno de los temas de capacitación para los moderadores diamantados en el programa que aún está por verse cuando sería lanzado.

Relacionado

- [Presentando "The Loop": Una base para escuchar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4454/65)

Comment: "La Compañía" en mayusculas. Me encanta :)

Comment: El tema de género está asociado a lo que algunos teóricos sociales llama **visibilización** de la mujer en el lenguaje (que por ser supuestamente patriarcal la oculta) y da lugar a el uso de doble sujeto en los enunciados. Si se cede en ese asunto vamos a tener que usar las otras tres vocales para incluir homosexuales, transgenero y elles. (A los hermafroditas no se les pondrá vocal).